# Bootstrap 12 column layout breaks even there is two more column space remaning

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Im using a non bootstrap application to which I recently integrated boostrap styling (CSS files). But am facing a strange issue in grid layout. Here is the screen shot of the issue.
[image]

Here the first label column is **col-md-2**, then dropdown column **col-md-5**, and the last column (With button group) is only **col-md-4**. But the last column got breaks into new line.

Here is the markup

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class=" panel-heading">
                                <i class="fa fa-apple"></i>
                                Manage Questionnaire</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">

                                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class=" col-md-2 control-label">
                                                    Account</label>
                                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                                    <select class="form-control">
                                                        <option value="value">text</option>
                                                    </select></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="col-md-2 control-label">
                                                    Survey</label>
                                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                                    <select class="form-control ">
                                                        <option value="value">text</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                                    <div class="btn-group">
                                                        <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LinkButton3','')" class="btn btn-default" id="LinkButton3"> <i class="fa fa-file-o"></i></a>
                                                        <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LinkButton4','')" class="btn btn-default" id="LinkButton4"> <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                                                        <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LinkButton5','')" class="btn btn-danger" id="LinkButton5"> <i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="col-md-2 control-label">
                                                    Section</label>
                                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                                    <select class="form-control">
                                                        <option value="value">text</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                                    <div class="btn-group">
                                                        <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LinkButton1','')" class="btn btn-default" id="LinkButton1"> <i class="fa fa-file-o"></i></a>
                                                        <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LinkButton2','')" class="btn btn-default" id="LinkButton2"> <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                                                        <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LinkButton6','')" class="btn btn-danger" id="LinkButton6"> <i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Am not getting why its not get fit in one line since its only total 11 if we add the column length of those rows

Answer (score 1):

Try to put them in a separate div with a new row and with full 12 columns - I have used only one segment of your code, this should work;

```
<div class=row>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">
                Section</label>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option value="value">text</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LinkButton1','')" class="btn btn-default" id="LinkButton1"> <i class="fa fa-file-o"></i></a>
                    <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LinkButton2','')" class="btn btn-default" id="LinkButton2"> <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                    <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LinkButton6','')" class="btn btn-danger" id="LinkButton6"> <i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But according to bootstrap theory does it require "row" when Im using form-group along with form-horizontal. In thoery it says when combined use of form-group and form-horizontal form-group act the same as row.